# Lost Date-Information with JAX-RS 2.0 and Glassfish 4

Tags: json, web-services, jax-rs, glassfish-4

i implement an simple REST-WebService with JAX-RS 2.0 and Glassfish 4. My problem is, if i send an Date or Calendar to the WS, the pojo lost the Dateinformation an the values are NULL.
In my WebService i set the Date `tmp.setDate(1)` and in my JUnit-Test-Case i get the information *[Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 CET 1970]* 
Any ideas why i lost the dateinformation by the request?

My Client (JUNIT)

```
@Test
public void testPOST() {
client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
this.root = this.client.target(SERVER + "/restExample/example");

    OriginalSimpleDTO dto = new OriginalSimpleDTO();
    dto.setDate(new Date(1));

    final Entity<OriginalSimpleDTO> entity = Entity.entity(dto, mediaType);
    Response response = this.root.request().post(entity);
    System.out.println("POST Status " + response.getStatus());
    OriginalSimpleDTO tmp = response.readEntity(OriginalSimpleDTO.class);
    System.out.println("POST tmp-Date [" + tmp.getDate() + "]");

}
```

My WebSerice-Resource

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response testPost(OriginalSimpleDTO dto) {
    System.out.println("dto date [" + dto.getDate() + "]");

    OriginalSimpleDTO tmp = new OriginalSimpleDTO();
    tmp.setDate(new Date(1));

    return Response.ok(tmp).build(); 
}
```

My Pojo

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonInclude (Include.NON_NULL)
public class OriginalSimpleDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Date datum;

    //default Constructor
   public OriginalSimpleDTO() {}

   @JsonSerialize (using = DateSerializer.class)
   public Date getDatum() {
      return datum;
   }

   @JsonDeserialize (using = DateDeserializer.class)
   public void setDatum(Date datum) {
      this.datum = datum;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the different versions of Jackson-Provider inside the glassfish 4, not correct initialize the provider.

See [REST webservice don't use my JsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763004/rest-webservice-dont-use-my-jsonserializer/18808743#18808743)

Answer (score 0):

Okay the solution that I posted before was not correct, the correct answer was to use a ISO 8601 format so what really worked was the following sting below

**Using Glassfish4, JAX-RS2.0, NO other custom code (de-serializer)**

**Domain class**

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
Date timeMiliStart;
WebResource
```

**WebResource**

```
@Path("/post/json")
@POST   
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response createBaseJson(Base base){
```

**JSON (Postman POST) Call attempted that kept failing**

```
{"baseStr":"My new Car","languageId":1,"timeMiliStart":"2013-11-15 15:42:13.300","timeMiliEnd":"2013-11-15 15:42:16.521"}
```

**JSON (Postman POST) Call attempted that succeeded**

```
{"baseStr":"My new Car","languageId":1,"timeMiliStart":"1972-10-02T21:16:31.347+01:00","timeMiliEnd":"1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00"}
```